# Has anybody got angular2 quickstart working?

Tags: angular

I think I did all the steps from https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html and even added system.js to index.html, but sill no Hello Alice. Has anybody got it working?

Update:
Ok, when i'm trying to build it with gulp (tutorial doesn't mention it, but looks like it's necessary) i'm getting this:

```
user@edbwp400322:~/dvl/mongo/quickstart$ gulp 
[16:46:31] Using gulpfile ~/dvl/mongo/quickstart/gulpfile.js
[16:46:31] Starting 'default'...
[16:46:31] Starting 'clean'...
[16:46:31] Finished 'clean' after 25 ms
[16:46:31] Starting 'build:ng2'...
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.12 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.12 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.12 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.12 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.12 No repository field.
[16:46:37] Finished 'build:ng2' after 6.16 s
[16:46:37] Starting 'build:shim'...
[16:46:37] Finished 'build:shim' after 21 ms
[16:46:37] Starting 'build:strip_maps'...
sed: невозможно прочитать : Нет такого файла или каталога
[16:46:37] 'build:strip_maps' errored after 49 ms
[16:46:37] Error in plugin 'gulp-shell'
Message:
    Command failed: sed: can't read: no such file or directory

Details:
    killed: false
    code: 2
    signal: null
    stdout: 
    stderr: sed: can't read: no such file or directory

[16:46:37] 'default' errored after 6.26 s
[16:46:37] Error: [object Object]
    at formatError (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/home/user/dvl/mongo/quickstart/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /home/user/dvl/mongo/quickstart/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/home/user/dvl/mongo/quickstart/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/home/user/dvl/mongo/quickstart/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at finish (/home/user/dvl/mongo/quickstart/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:48:5)
    at Gulp.onError (/home/user/dvl/mongo/quickstart/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:55:4)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:117:20)
user@edbwp400322:~/dvl/mongo/quickstart$
```

the sed (stream editor for filtering and transforming text) is installed. But I'm still not sure it's gulp can't find sed or sed can't find some file. 
I realize that this update doesn't make question more specific, but it would be nice to know that quickstart is working for somebody.

Update 2: sed woes were caused by https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/strip_maps.sh. Moving filename into '' fixes the problem.

Update 3: got it build with gulp, no more 404, but still no Hello Alice and this error in console:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "app" at http://127.0.0.1:8081/app.es6
>   http://127.0.0.1:8081/app.es6:3:1: Unexpected token @ (WARNING: non-Error used)es6-module-loader.src.js:140 (anonymous function)es6-module-loader.src.js:167 fes6-module-loader.src.js:189 i

Comment: Check this [ng2-play](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play) repo, it is currently working well out of the box

Comment: Having the same problems. Can you elaborate on Update 2 please? Where did you put the filename into quotes? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember exactly waht I did and can't check now, but most likely it was 


sed -e '/^\/\/\# source/d' -i 'dist/es6-shim.js'

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can, but there is a mistake in the official document.

You need to change `<reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" >` to `///<reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />`

And DO NOT change the load order in `index.html`, systemjs must come befor angular

Answer (score 0):

If http-server is running from quickstart folder then index.html shouldn't contain 'quickstart' in pathes to scripts:

index

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
    <script src="/dist/es6-shim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- The app component created in app.es6 -->
<my-app></my-app>
<script>
    // Rewrite the paths to load the files
    System.paths = {
        'angular2/*':'/angular2/*.js', // Angular
        'rtts_assert/*': '/rtts_assert/*.js', //Runtime assertions
        'app': 'app.es6' // The my-app component
    };

    // Kick off the application
    System.import('app');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.es6 remains as in tuturoial.

And if it's running from upper folder then it's just can't find anything, although there may be some switches which I'm not aware of.